# Java - Android Studio - Method inside class with complete Handler

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Java (Android Studio), I need to create class and inside this class a method that load anything and after it finish loading, it invoke event on the main instance, which communicate with the main instance, for example in Xcode Swift IOS you can define method with completeHandler:

```
public static func getTheImage( imagePath: String,completeHanlder: @escaping (UIImage)->Void)
{
completeHanlder(image)
}
```

and when you call the method

```
WriteFileHandlingMozeh.getTheImage(imagePath) 
   { 
      (img) in
     // do something here
   }
```

Comment: What is "complete handler"?

Comment: Maybe you want AsyncTask?

Comment: I mean by complete hanlder an event that the method can invoke when finish the job

Comment: see my second comment

Comment: is this java?So different

Comment: You should also look at image loading libraries like Picasso.

Comment: I agree to [Code-Apprentice](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice), use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of AsyncTask for image loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
protected class YourClassName extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                //Load anything
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                //Once the loading is completed this function is called


            }
        }
```

calling the above function,

```
new YourClassName.execute();
```

this will execute the code in `doInBackground(String... params)` first and then `onPostExecute(String s)`

Answer (score 0):

Android is so different deal with activity live cycle you can load you data for example in `onResume()` this is the state in which the application interacts with the user, you can read more about activity life cycle from [the official documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)